# How do I get a specific element from a std::list?

Tags: c++, list

I have been using Java for a long time and decided to change to C++. I have already made a list like this:

```
std::list <Player*> players;
```

And all I want to do is to get a specific element from this list. I remember in Java calling a ".get(index)" method but I can't find something similar in C++.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Advice -- don't use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  Learn C++ as if Java doesn't exist.

Comment: A `std::list` is an implementation of a *linked list*, thus indexing is not available.  These are the details that go missing if you try to equate or match Java  with C++.

Comment: Use `std::vector` as your default choice of container. It provides the feature you want and for many (most?) use cases it is even faster than `std::list` although that may seem counter-intuitive at first. Here are [some benchmarks](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html).

Comment: C++ standard library documentation isn't kept secret, you know?

Comment: BTW, you should copy variables into a list, not use pointers in the list.  The C++ language does not require variables to be dynamically allocated before they are used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `std::list` class does not offer random access. You can think of it more like a linked list.

For random access, use `std::vector` or `std::deque` instead. Then you can read `players[index]`.

If you're committed to `std::list`, then you can get *linear-time* random access by advancing an iterator to the position you need. For example:

```
std::list<Player*>::const_iterator it = players.begin();
std::advance(it, index);
```

Now `*it` refers to the element you wanted. If you have C++11 or later, you can shorten the above to a single statement:

```
auto it = std::next(players.begin(), index);
```

Comment: Is there not a way for example to get the 2nd item from this list?

Comment: @N.Spyropoulos -- A `std::list` is a linked list.  There is no such thing as going directly to a specific item in a random-access fashion.

Comment: To get to the second item, start at the first and advance the iterator once. To get to the hundredth item, start at the first and advance the iterator 99 times.

Comment: @N. Spyropoulos    For random access, use `std::array`, `std::vector` or `std::deque`.